# Get information when the server started running (nestJs)

Tags: nestjs

I want to get information into a variable when my server started running.

Is there an order that gives me this?

Comment: `app.listen(port, hostname, callback)`

Comment: What information? What are you trying to get/use?

Comment: I meant the information I want is the time my server started running